# Nautilus: Mark files in directory as favorite

Tags: nautilus, photo-management

I have a digital camera since 15 years. My son is 13 now and we want to create a book with photos of his childhood.

This means my wife and me we need to select our favorite photos.

I look at the directories with nautilus. After hitting "ctrl +" the images are big enough, so that we can scan the directories with our human eyes easily.

Is there a way to mark files/images as "favorite" in nautilus?

There are a lot of photos (76k). Stored in the structure YYYY/YYYY-MM/YYYY-MM-DD. There are 2k directories.

Any hints?

Comment: There are several packages, gleaned from `apt-cache search photo`: `shotwell - digital photo organizer`, `digikam - digital photo management application for KDE`, `gnome-photos- application to access, organize and share your photos with GNOME`, `gphotofs - filesystem to mount digital cameras`, and on and on.

Comment: @waltinator why do I need a special photo-management package? Imagine I have several thousand mp3/ogg files and I want to mark some of them... But, yes maybe it is better to choose a photo management package.

Comment: @guettli why should a general purpose file manager have all sorts of photo, music, document, video, source code management features?

Comment: Marlin file manager can mark labels by colors. http://www.techphylum.com/2016/06/say-hello-to-marlin-smart-and.html But, it's not an official ubuntu package.

Comment: Some time ago I answered something similar.Please see http://askubuntu.com/q/803644/295286 Let me know if this is a suitable solution for your needs , whether you have a request to modify it for your case, etc.  Personally it seems that your question needs a little more clarification and specifics on how you want files to be marked as favorite

Comment: Marking/labelling files is not too difficult. Some work, but very well possible. What is not totally clear to me, looking at the numbers, would you label them one by one individually, or complete driectories, or from selection criteria?

Comment: @JacobVlijm In my current use case I want to select individual images (not directories).

Comment: @guettli  Hi, have you reviewed the link I posted previously ?

Comment: @Serg I am sorry, I missed. Yes, this is a work-around. Looks easier than nautilus-actions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really must do it from within nautilus, check out the option below (I personally think something like Shotwell or creating a fav folder would be better).

Summary: Use a nautilus script to create a context menu option that will create links or rename files to "mark" them as favorites.

---

First create your script in the editor of your choice that will designate files as favorites. I include two scripts below that can be copy/pasted and used for this purpose.

**Example script 1:** Designate files by changing the name

Files marked as favorites will be renamed so they are listed before all other files. This is accomplished by prepending "*0 " to the filename. In this way, the file is visually marked with <strike>a star</strike> an asterisk, and the file is positionally separated from all files not marked as favorites. The context menu item toggles the favorite designation.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# set IFS environment variable for reading selected file names
defaultIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

while read item
do
    [ "$item" == "" ] && exit # the last line is blank. Don't try to process it
    name=$(basename $item) # get just the filename
    if [ "${name:0:3}" == "*0 " ]; then
        mv "$name" "${name:3}" # if the name begins with "*0 ", remove it
    else
        mv "$name" "*0 $name" # if the name doesn't begin with "*0 ", add it
    fi
done <<< "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" # pass the arguments (list of files) to the loop

# reset IFS to original value if necessary
IFS="$defaultIFS"
```

**Example script 2:** Designate files by creating a link in a "favorites" directory

This approach creates a link to files marked as favorites in a predetermined "favorites" folder. This script does not toggle the favorite designation.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# set IFS environment variable for reading selected file names
defaultIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

# if our favorites directory doesn't exist, create it
favDir="$HOME/My_Favorites"
[ ! -d "$favDir" ] && mkdir -p "$favDir"

while read item
do
    [ "$item" == "" ] && exit # the last line is blank. Don't try to process it
    ln -s "$item" "$favDir" # this will fail if a link with the same basename as item is already in $favDir
done <<< "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" # pass the arguments (list of files) to the loop

# reset IFS to original value if necessary
IFS="$defaultIFS"
```

Once your script is complete, save it in the `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` folder. The name you use to save this file will be the context-menu item created (less file extentsion). Finally, you need to make the script as executable. Now there should be able to select files, right-click, and choose Scripts -> *Favorites-script*. Where "Favorites-script" is the name of the script you created.

*Note: I read somewhere (and don't remember where now) that if the context-menu option doesn't show up immediately, you should try navigating to* `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` *in nautilus. I don't know if this is necessary or not.*

Comment: I think this is too complicated for me.

Comment: @guettli, sorry, I don't think I can make it any simpler than installing a program and running a script. Since nautilus doesn't have built-in what you're looking for, it's going to take a bit extra to make it happen in Nautilus. Give it a go once and see. Everything that I say to run can be copy and pasted into a terminal (right-click in terminal to paste). If you can get through it once, you'll have a context-menu option. If it doesn't work, your best bet is probably to go the route that [muru](http://askubuntu.com/a/892537/606758) or [Peetah](http://askubuntu.com/a/892531/606758) suggests.

Comment: the problem is me. I don't copy+paste and execute scripts which I don't understand. Maybe this is paranoid, but I want to know what is going on. I trust you and that this snippet does what it should. Writing my script is not the problem. Why is it not enough to copy my script to a special folder in the nautilus config?

Comment: @guettli, I understand not running scripts you don't understand. I don't think the ability to drop a script in a nautilus config folder works anymore. If you have a script that you wrote, try using nautilus-actions (mentioned in my post) to run your script. If you pass "%B" with the quotes as a parameter for your script in nautilus-actions, it will pass the names of selected files in single-quotes to your script. `"$(grep -oP "'.*?'" <<< "$@")"` in my script breaks the file names out onto separate lines. _Beware, nautilus-actions requires an absolute path to your script. ~/ won't work._

Comment: Drop a script in a nautilus config folder does not work any more? This answer is quite young (year 2016): http://askubuntu.com/a/805415/42348 AFAIK this answer goes this way.

Comment: @guettli, I tried that one before I made my post above, and it didn't work. I figured out why, and I have it working now. I'll change my answer above to use that method.

Comment: thank you for the update of the answer. Creating a nautilus context menue entry is much simpler this way. This way we learned both something new :-)

Comment: Now I need to call this context menu script via a keyboard short-cut. I created a new question for this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/892553/nautilus-custom-action-on-selected-files-via-keyboard-short-cut

Comment: Nice concept! Smart.

Answer (score 3):

When I don't feel like using Shotwell for photo selection, my workflow goes like this:

1. Create a new directory, say `fav`
2. Open `fav` and the folder with pictures in two tabs (or, if an older Nautilus, or using Nemo, in two panes)
3. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and use the arrow keys for navigating through the pics (usually, only tapping <kbd>→</kbd>), and tapping <kbd>Space</kbd> to select pictures of interest.
4. Periodically, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>  and drag selected pictures to other pane/tab to create links in the `fav` folder.

Comment: I like this workflow. I was not aware that you can create a second tab in nautilus. Yes, thank you for the next hint: ctrl-shift-drag creates symlinks --- nice. thank you.

Comment: Actually, I Ctrl-drag to create copies instead of links (since I'll usually edit the selected pics too), which means that I just need to find something to keep Ctrl pressed. But with 74k photos, making copies can be rather space-consuming.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not selecting the pictures via nautilus, but via `Shotwell` (comes pre-installed with Ubuntu). Nautilus is a file browser, not a selection tool.

You will immediately have an overview of which pictures were made on what day (organised in events), and you can add a rating and tags to the pictures. All files will also remain in their respective folders, not messing up your file organisation.

76k pictures is a whole lot tough, and depending on the image size, it could take a long long time to index them all, but in the end you will have an easily accessible database of pictures.

Comment: Nautilus is not a good tool for selecting files?

Comment: Not for selecting pictures. Shotwell is exactly made to select pictures. Right now you have all of your directories set up for date, Shotwell will not mess with the location of the files.