# Nautilus: Custom Action on selected files via keyboard short-cut

Tags: command-line, keyboard, nautilus, shortcut-keys

1. I open a directory containing about 100 files in nautilus
2. I select N (maybe 10) files by looking at the preview of the file.
3. Now I would like to hit short-cut and my custom script should be called.
4. My custom script receives the file names and does what I want it to do.

How can I register a custom action in gnome/ubuntu/nautilus which receives the file names which are selected in nautilus?

## New context entry in context menu of nautilus

If you write a script in ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts, then you get a new entry in the context menu. How to call this script via a short-cut?

## Background

This is a follow-up question to [Nautilus: Mark files in directory as favorite](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891508/nautilus-mark-files-in-directory-as-favorite/892537)

## Version

I use Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Running actions on selected files

The answer below will first literally answer your question;

> how to call a script and use the currently selected files as arguments **`[1]`**.

However, the accepted answer in the linked question uses *nautilus scripts*, which take files as arguments from nautilus. ***That does not work from a shortcut***, only when right-clicked *in* nautilus. In `[2]`, I therefore added the functionality of the scripts from the linked question to the answer, so you only need to run either one of them (in `[2]`)  from a shortcut.

---

#### `[1]` For 16.04 and higher*, running a script with selected files as arguments

You can simply use the short script below. It will "read" the currently selected files and run your script with the files as arguments.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import pyperclip
import time

time.sleep(1)
subprocess.call(["xdotool", "key", "Control_L+c"])

for item in pyperclip.paste().splitlines():
    subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/script", item])
```

#### To use

1. install `python3-pyperclip` and `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-pyperclip xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `run_withselected.py` Replace in the script

   ```
   "/path/to/script"
   ```

   by the actual path to the script you want to run. **Use absolute paths**, in quotes.
3. Add it to a shortut key: Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/run_withselected.py
   ```

---

### `[2]` However

Note that the linked nautilus script from the other answer will not run like this however, since it retrieves its arguments in another way ***from nautilus directly***. I therefore *combined* the functionality of the script from the linked question, with the one above.

You don't need the other script(s) from the other answer anymore then.

#### A. Designate files by changing the name

*select files*

[image]

*press shortcut to mark (toggle) the files*

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import pyperclip
import shutil
import os
import time

time.sleep(1)

def npath(p, f):
    return os.path.join(p, f)

subprocess.call(["xdotool", "key", "Control_L+c"])
for item in pyperclip.paste().splitlines():
    data = item.rsplit("/", 1); path = data[0]; name = data[1]
    newname = name[2:] if name.startswith("*0") else "*0"+name
    shutil.move(npath(path, name), npath(path, newname))
```

#### B. Designate files by creating a link in a "favorites" directory

*select files*

[image]

*press shortcut to create (toggle) a link in "My_Favorites"*

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import pyperclip
import shutil
import os
import time

fav = os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], "My_Favorites")

try:
    os.mkdir(fav)
except FileExistsError:
    pass

time.sleep(1)

subprocess.call(["xdotool", "key", "Control_L+c"])
for item in pyperclip.paste().splitlines():
    name = item.rsplit("/", 1)[-1]
    link = os.path.join(fav, name)
    try:
        os.symlink(item, link)
    except FileExistsError:
        os.remove(link)
```

#### To use (either one)

1. the scripts needs `python3-pyperclip` and `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-pyperclip xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `toggle_selected.py`
3. Add shortut key: Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/toggle_selected.py
   ```

#### Explanation

1. The script uses `xdotool` to virtually press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
2. Subsequently, the script (internally) creates a list of selected files:

   ```
   pyperclip.paste().splitlines()
   ```
3. These files are subsequently used as arguments to either rename the files:

   ```py
   for item in pyperclip.paste().splitlines():
       data = item.rsplit("/", 1); path = data[0]; name = data[1]
       newname = name[2:] if name.startswith("*0") else "*0"+name
       shutil.move(npath(path, name), npath(path, newname))
   ```

   or create a symlink:

   ```py
   for item in pyperclip.paste().splitlines():
       name = item.rsplit("/", 1)[-1]
       try:
           os.symlink(item, os.path.join(fav, name))
       except FileExistsError:
           os.remove(link)
   ```
4. The `time.sleep(1)` finally is to make sure "real" key press does not interfere with the simulated keypress by `xdotool`.

   #### Notes

   - In the linked answer, the *second* script creates the link, but does not toggle. I made answer "B" also toggle the existence of the symlink.
   - If it were for a published application, I would combine A and B into one script, and decide what action to take in a settings file. I might add that later.

---

#### *14.04

...will require a different procedure for installing pyperclip:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip xdotool
sudo pip3 install pyperclip
```