# Can I customize Keyboard shortcuts? (Nautilus)

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, nautilus

[image: customize nautilus shortcut]

> I just want to customize shortcuts for two actions i.e. **Switching next tab** & **Switching previous tab**. These two actions have already shortcuts assigned (**Ctrl+PgUp** & **Ctrl+PgDn**). I want to overwrite with my new keys.

Any help would be helpful. 
Thank You.

Comment: You may want to see https://askubuntu.com/a/894220/295286 Nautilus doesn't allow setting custom shortcuts. But you can set desktop environment shortcut which will detect when you have Nautilus window in focus and via `xdotool` command execute a shortcut that Nautilus understands. That is a method of indirection, but works nicely

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy okay, so this was helpful though was a bit long process. So isn't there any short lengthy process?