# Add rank file functionality

Tags: 16.04

The problem:

I have many files (e.g. scientific papers) in one folder. I want to create SOME distinction between them, so I know which one are more important than the other.

My solution:
Add some UI functionality to rank a file, just as you can rank music files (in some other setting).

In practice:
So I need to add some visualization to select the 'rank' of a file, and display it as well.

I thought that there would be some simple 'application' but I am not able to find anything that even resembles my solution.. Maybe one of you can help in the right direction?

Example of solution:
[image]

Comment: There's nothing like that so far. As workaround I suggest https://askubuntu.com/a/805415/295286 to bookmark important files. But I'll take this as consideration for my upcoming project, and eventually maybe post an answer ( which will be probably done in like next 4 months or so )

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks for the comment. Since I like to learn stuff myself as well... how do you start a project like this?
Do you know any tutorial that explain how you can add functionalities to your UI in Ubuntu? Where can I start to learn this?

Comment: Honestly, I've been just googling a lot :) But without joking, it took a lot of research and time over the past 4 years. What I do is mostly write in Python. I've learned how to use basics of the language, then `gi.repository` module which has some of the things that are made for GUI and GNOME. Specifically, they contain Gtk - the functions for graphics library that GNOME and all GNOME-based desktops use, as well as Gio - which is for low level functionality. Here's a good place to start for Gtk: https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html

Comment: Ah great! I am quite familiar with Python as well.. so it is good to see that you can interact with GNOME in that way. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: For the particular use-case in your question, it sounds like what you want is a citation manager that supports a custom ranking field - see for example [JabRef: special fields](http://help.jabref.org/en/SpecialFields#ranking)

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference and a note to myself... I think I have found a good direction for this solution...

https://gist.github.com/escoand/cf1605f7e0410b319fcb

That gives a way to add columns to the list view in Nautilus. It is not a perfect solution for me yet, since this deals with mp3's and their meta-data.

However, I think the approach will bring me in the right direction :)